# Unable to access external URLs from within Docker Container

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to access an external URL from within my Docker Container running on an AWS EC2 Instance.

Though I'm able to CURL from the EC2 Instance - the same CURL doesn't work from within the Docker container. 
Essentially this CURL works in the EC2 Instance but NOT within the Docker Container. Why would that be?

> curl https://elasticsearch.myorg.com

Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.5.0
ENV ELASTICSEARCH_URL=https://elasticsearch.myorg.com
EXPOSE 5601
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/kibana-docker"]
```

Comment: Is that url supposed to be a real example or just a placeholder?

Comment: The url is a placeholder. Since it points to a Rout53 elastic endpoint within my Organization - didnt see the point of mentioning the actual endpoint. The point here is, i can curl that elasticsearch endpoint from within the EC2. But from within the docker container - it times out

Comment: Have you tried attaching to the docker container and pinging the endpoint from there?

Comment: Sorry could u clarify this a bit more ? "have you tried attaching to the docker container"? Attach what specifically? If you mean If ive tried running the docker contain in interactive mode and logging in and pinging the endpoint from there.thats how i figured out the curl isnt working from the container

Comment: What's the response message from trying that?

Comment: It just hangs.. I did notice something though. If i run elasticsearch LOCALLY and I start my kibana using this command (to bind network bridge to localhost) everything works fine  `docker run -d -p 33000:5601 --net=host -e ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://localhost:9200` . This however DOESNT work when I change my ELASTICSEARCH_URL to `https://elasticsearch.myorg.com` . I feel that somewhere docker networking is coming into play which i'm not aware of

Answer (score 8):

So after a LOT of trial and error, I finally figured out the problem. It looks like running the docker image using the standard:

> docker run -d -p 5601:5601 my-kibana-image:1

doesnt suffice. The host resolution to elasticsearch (which is an external host) ONLY works when I change the network configuration from the default to "host". Doing this

> docker run  --net=host -d -p 5601:5601 my-kibana-image:1

finally fixed the issue and the kibana container instance was FINALLY able to talk to elasticsearch!!! Kibana bootstrapped correctly and I was able to bring it up fine at this point.